# Trello API: how to get board ids of an organisation or member

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, trello

I am working on a Trello sync bot based off of the GitHub one here : https://github.com/fiatjaf/trello-cardsync and I am working on the coffeescript files. I have looked on the API and I think I know what I need I just don't know how to write it exactly and I can't find any examples of it especially in coffeescript (or javascript).

I would like to be able to search through an organisations boards or a members boards and then pick out certain board IDs so I get just a list of board IDs to certain boards I want, so then I can create webhooks for these boards.

I've tried using `Trello.get("members/me/boards", { fields: "id, name"})` to get all the boards IDs and names like in the client.js API 'Trello.get(path[, params], success, error)' but my GET just returns `unidentified` when I try to print it to console. I have an array of objects in the `settings.coffee` file to compare the names with to select the boards I want but I can't get the full list in my file. At the moment I'm just looking at the data from the link: https://trello.com/1/members/my/boards?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&token=substitutethispartwiththeauthorizationtokenthatyougotfromtheuserand entering the IDs manually to create the webhooks, but I would like to automate this as much as possible.

I have also looked at 'GET /1/search' in Trello API but I'm unsure how to do that in my coffeescript file.

Comment: Are you looking at the return value of `Trello.get`?  You need to pass it a callback.

Comment: @AaronDufour what would that look like? I don't know what it should look like in the coffeescript, is it like when you use `Trello.putAsync()`?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @AaronDufour I'm pretty new to javascript in general so not sure what you are referring to exactly, I'm working off the GitHub Trello Card Sync files on a cloud server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a callback to `Trello.get`.  It doesn't return anything meaningful, but instead passes the value to the callback:

```
Trello.get("members/me/boards", { fields: "id,name"}, function(err, boards) {
  console.log(boards); // got them!
  console.log(err); // if something went wrong, this will be non-null
})
```

Comment: when i run this 'boards' comes out as random characters `ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½X` (a lot of stuff like this) and 'err' is null

Comment: please look above ^ what can i do with boards to get the ids out?

Comment: does this code work? it's throwing error "Trello is not defined"